# PostgreSQL: Arrays Data Type with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql

I'm working on PostgeSQL with PHP and I know that PosrgeSQL allow columns of a table to be defined as arrays.

So let's say I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE sal_emp (
    a            text ARRAY,
    b            text ARRAY,
    c            text ARRAY,
);
```

These are my arrays:

```
$a = array(aa,bb,cc);
$b = array(dd,dd,aa);
$c = array(bb,ff,ee);
```

and I want to insert them into respective column each like this:

```
     a     |     b      |      c     
-----------+------------+------------
{aa,bb,cc} | {dd,dd,aa} |  {bb,ff,ee}
```

---

Can I insert it this way?

```
$a = implode(',', $a);
$b = implode(',', $b);
$c = implode(',', $c);
$a = array('a' => $a, 'b' => $b, 'c' => $c);
pg_insert($dbconn, 'table', $a);
```

Or is there a better way to achieve the same result?

Comment: It's just a matter of string manipulation to convert PHP's array into a string representation that Postgres will accept in a query: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html

Comment: @MarcB Yeah I know but I am just not sure if I get it correct and if there is a better way doing it. I'm very new to PostgreSQL..

Comment: The right way to do it is to normalize your database properly and not use PostgreSQL arrays at all.

Comment: You could look up this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068683/convert-postgresql-array-to-php-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your creation statement has an error. This is correct:

```
CREATE TABLE sal_emp (
    a            text ARRAY,
    b            text ARRAY,
    c            text ARRAY
);
```

If you were to insert manually you would do:

```
insert into sal_emp (a, b, c) values 
('{"some text"}', '{"some more", "a bit more"}', '{"even more"}');
```

or

```
insert into sal_emp (a, b, c) values 
(array ['some text'], array['some more', 'a bit more'], array['even more']);
```

So... I can't test it now but it would be something like this:

```
$a = "array['" . implode("'],['", $a) . "']";
...
$a = array('a' => $a, 'b' => $b, 'c' => $c);
pg_insert($dbconn, 'table', $a);
```