# Convert a string to array in PHP

Tags: json, postgresql, postgis

I execute a postgresql query to a database using PDO and I get back as repsonse strings in the form of:

```
POINT(23.7336253085595 38.0002872112492)
```

How can I get the numbers of these strings and store them into to different variables?

That's my code in order to send the query question:

```
include 'postgreConnect.php';



$maxGid = 1084;
for ($rowPostGis=1; $rowPostGis<=$maxGid;$rowPostGis++){

$stmt = $dbconn->prepare("SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Transform(geom, 4326)) AS geom FROM part_athens_centroids WHERE gid = :rowPostGis;");
$stmt->execute(array('rowPostGis' => $rowPostGis));

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $geom = $row['geom'];
    echo($geom);
    //echo($geom);
}   
}
```

Comment: You can set your SQL to return json and then convert it to php array. check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068683/convert-postgresql-array-to-php-array/13670706#13670706

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php this will convert your string into an array of strings that you can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php to convert each string to an int. You may need to crop the query result down to just the numbers for that use http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php.