# read postgres array from sql table using python pandas

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas

I tried to read postgres array from pandas like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2 as pg
con = pg.connect(con_info)
df = pd.read_sql(con,'select my_arr from my_table')
```

however what i'm getting is a string like so:

```
 my_arr
 ---------
'{1,2,3}'
```

I can parse the string, but I want to get it without any string manipulation as a python list.

thanks.

joseph.

Answer (score 0):

found one answer, using array_to_json solves this.

[Convert PostgreSQL array to PHP array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068683/convert-postgresql-array-to-php-array)
in python:

```
df = pd.read_sql(con,'select array_to_json(my_arr) from my_table')
```

the datatype in the column is a python list.
However, I wonder if there is a more natural way to do it.